# Python3.11 can't open file [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, cron

I updated **readOnlyRootFilesystem: true** in my cronjob yaml but started getting the error

OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/absolute/path/to/your/folder'

I further added an empty directory
volumeMounts:
- name: tmp-volume
mountPath: absolute/path/to/your/folder
volumes:

- name: tmp-volume
  emptyDir: {}

After adding this I am starting to get

```
**python3.11: can't open file 'absolute/path/to/your/folder/text.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**
```

I have attached the cronjob yaml

```
           containers:
            - env:
              - name: ENV_VAR
                value: value
              - name: MAINTAIN_HA_POOL
                value: "true"
              - name: PROCESS_SCHEDULER_REQUESTS
                value: "true"
              - name: MAINTAIN_NODE_POOL
                value: "false"
              - name: ENABLE_LSV3
                value: "false"
              image: us.icr.io/nz-cloud/nzsaas-common-pool-cronjob:master-2.1.2.0-20240329-111245
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: common-machine-pool-cronjob-container
              resources: {}
              securityContext:
                privileged: true
                readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /opt/ibm/common-pool-cronjob/
                name: tmp-volume
            volumes:
            - emptyDir: {}
              name: tmp-volume
```

FYI I have given CHMOD 777 to the particular folder

Comment: IIUC, you are mounting an empty folder (`emptyDir`} into `/absolute/path/to/your/folder` and then trying to access '/absolute/path/to/your/folder/text.py`. This file won't exist because the folder is **empty**.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, creating an `emptyDir` creates an empty folder.

You need to create `text.py` in the folder referenced by `emptyDir` before you can interact with it.

By way of example:

`app.yaml`:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: docker.io/alpine:3.19
        args:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          # The emptyDir volume's mount path
          DIR="/absolute/path/to/your/folder"
          # Some file
          FILE="text.py"
          echo "Starting"
          if ! test -f ${DIR}/${FILE}
          then
            echo "${FILE} does **not** exist"
          fi
          echo "Creating ${DIR}/${FILE}"
          touch ${DIR}/${FILE}
          if test -f ${DIR}/${FILE}
          then
            echo "${FILE} exists"
          fi
          echo "Done" 
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-volume
          mountPath: /absolute/path/to/your/folder
      volumes:
      - name: tmp-volume
        emptyDir:
          sizeLimit: 1Mi
```

And:

```bash
NAMESPACE="78244509"
kubectl create namespace ${NAMESPACE}

kubectl create \
--filename=./app.yaml \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}

kubectl logs deployment/app \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

Yields:

```
Starting
Creating /absolute/path/to/your/folder/text.py
text.py exists
Done
```

and:

```bash
kubectl delete \
--filename=./app.yaml \
--namespacpe=${NAMESPACE}
```